# When was first bitcoin transaction with fees?

Tags: transaction-fees, history

This is history question, but one with clear answer.

**I would like to know when(txid) was first transaction with fees ?** From my understanding in beginning there was more space than transaction so there where no fees.

**Additional, if anybody knows, block when at least 50% of transactions had fees ?** Maybe this is better metric, because probably somebody has done some transaction with fee on main-net for fun/test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first block with transactions that paid fees was  block 2817, the second was 12 983. To answer your question, I used blockchair.com’s block overview, [sorted the blocks by ascending height and filtered for a fee of at least one satoshi](https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/blocks?s=id(asc)&q=fee_total(1..)).

[image: Search result for first blocks with fees]

The three transactions that paid fees in block 2817 were:

- [5b62efcc…1c2902c2](https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/transaction/5b62efcc5b069ab78504483869b71a9cddff63eb123bafeadd4da13c1c2902c2)
- [65f75ac6…e16306c9](https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/transaction/65f75ac62da749585c152f0ffed3c3482687699ccba81582561590c4e16306c9)
- [f8bf1e88…3e058eb2](https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/transaction/f8bf1e886d6ba6e4927acf861cf5ab3e62af2d50a6b011427f0369fa3e058eb2)

I don’t have an immediate way to answer the question about half the transactions paying fees.

Comment: Incidentally, the first block with over 50% of transactions paying fees is also block 2817, because the three transactions are the only transactions in that block (except for coinbase).

Comment: Touché, you’re right. I guess I just automatically extrapolated the question to mean the first full block that had 50% txs paying fees, but that was in fact never asked. :)

Comment: @Murch  "block when at least 50% of transactions had fees ?", my idea was to know when at least 50% of transaction had to pay fees to be included in block and never went under 50%. But then I should also add that block need to be full and it is getting complicated. To get some idea when fees became "mandatory". But it is not so important.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://transactionfee.info/charts/fees-package-feerates/?start=2010-10-03&end=2011-06-17, the chart seems to show that a 50th percentile for feerates appeared end of 2010.